# Copy an attribute in ArcPad EXCLUDING the unique Identifier

Tags: arcpad

I'd like to use the toggle button to 'copy attributes' when creating points in ArcPad.  Currently, I can't because I'm using the date (+ time) field as my unique identifier to link to related tables.

Is there any way to exclude an attribute (in my case the unique id) from the copy attributes toggle action?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving your editing workflow to use some of the Esri templates. This allows you to setup rules for attribute transfers while editing amongst other things. I would highly recommend looking at the following template. It was built for Water/Wastewater but I have implemented it for other uses outside of the utility industry.

http://www.arcgis.com/rc/item.html?id=14bdfb26bc2f4e0388a633fbd0ccca02

The download will be somewhat large because they include an example geodatabase. You will want to look at the documentation for the Attribute Assistant. Once you start reading that document your head will start spinning with the possibilities. You can with this template generate your own unique id's whenever a new feature is generated, you can also track date/timestamp fields, and which users made the edits based on windows login credentials or db credentials. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry -- I inadvertently posted ArcMap in the question when I'm looking for this sort of action in ArcPad!